# Scale up a nodejs app on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have nodejs app running on AWS EC2.

I would like to scale it up by creating more instances of it.

I don't quite understand how to do it on the networking side.

Lets say I create another instance and it's listening to a different port.
Should I change the client side to request from two different ports? I believe this could lead to race conditions on the DB

Am I suppose to listen on one port on the EC2 machine and direct the request to one of the instances? In that case the port will be busy until the instance is done with the request instead of processing requests in parallel with the other instance

Does anyone has some pointers or maybe can point me to some documents about this subject?

Comment: You can start by explaining what your Node.js application actually does.  What is the client?  An HTTP client?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's a MERN app

Comment: Sounds like you want to use node.js clustering with a sticky load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

At the basic level, you'll have multiple instances of your Node.js application, connecting to a common database backend.  (Your database should be clustered as well, but that's a topic for another post.)

If you're following best practices already, one request will be one response, and it won't matter if subsequent requests land on a different application server.  That is, the client could hit any of them at any time and there won't be any side effects.  If not, you'll need some sort of server pinning (usually done via cookie or similar methods) to ensure clients always land on the same application server.

The simplest way to load balance is to have your clients connect to a host name, and that hostname resolved round-robin style to several hosts.  This will spread the traffic around, but not necessarily correctly.  For instance, a particular command or issue on one host could mean it can only handle 5 requests, while the other servers can handle 5000.  Most cloud providers have management of load balancing.  AWS certainly does.

Since you're already on AWS, I'd recommend you deploy your application via Elastic Beanstalk.  It automates the spin-up/tear-down as-configured.  You could certainly roll your own solution, but it's probably just easier to use what's already there.  The load balancer is configured with Beanstalk.

Comment: They are all connected to a MongoDB running on the machine. I liked the idea with the cookie, so you mean each client will be handled by one specific server defined in the cookie, correct? I didn't quite understand what you mean about several host names? do you mean multiple EC2 machines?

Comment: @EdgarBarber You would run one database instance (or one cluster of instances) and connect to it from your application servers.

Comment: @EdgarBarber I didn't say several host names, I said several hosts.  That could be an EC2 machine, yes.

Comment: So lets say I have http://www.example.com/get_recipes endpoint set on my nodejs instances. This endpoint is being called from two different clients. I would like to handle the requests in parallel by my two servers. What I don't understand is how can I handle the second request while the first one is still being handle? Lets say I write a python server using flask to load balance it, can I get the second request while the first one is still being handle by one of the instances?

Comment: @EdgarBarber You can do your example with a single Node.js instance.  No need for two.  Node.js can handle requests in parallel.  Your database can too, since you're just getting data.